# Evaluating limits using Taylor expansions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, taylor-expansion

The limits are

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{\cos{x}-e^{-x^2/2}}{x^4})$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x\cdot\!\sin{x}-x(1+x)}{x^3}$$

Probably wrong things that I've tried

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\cos{x}-e^{-x^2/2}}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to 0}(\frac{1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+o(x^5)-1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4}+o(x^4)}{x^4})$

$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x\cdot\!\sin{x}-x(1+x)}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2))(x+o(x^2))-x-x^2)}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{x^3}{2}+o(x^2)}{x^3}=1/2$

Could you please help me understand how these kinds of limits can be computed I keep getting all of them wrong and if this goes on for a little bit longer I may have a panic attack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first rule is that, when you use Taylor's expansion, you use it *at the same order* for all terms. The second rule is that, when you have a product of expansions, or a composition, you expand it with the usual rules for polynomials, and *truncate the result* at the chosen order.

I'll start it for the first example, for which you had an error in the expansion of the exponential. We'll expand at order $4$:
\begin{align}
\cos x- \mathrm e^{-x^2/2}
&=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}+o\bigl(x^4\bigr)-\Bigl(1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}8+o\bigl(x^4\bigr)\Bigr)\\
&=\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^4}8+o\bigl(x^4\bigr)=-\frac{x^4}{12}+o\bigl(x^4\bigr)
\end{align}

Comment: Dear Bernard thank you for answering to my question. I have one more (but even if you won't give me an answer that'll be fine). Could you please tell me what I should do with the $o(x^n)$ 's  when I have something like $x*o(x^2)$ or $o(x^3)+o(x^4)$ or $o(x^2)*o(x)$. This really confuses me and if you could explain it to me I would get a much higher score on my upcoming test. ---Best Regards, Britanica

Comment: @Britanica: Well, it's  rather simple: $xo(x^2)=o(x^3)$. The same is valid for $o(x^2)\,o(x)$ Last, as $x^4=o(x^3)$, we have $(x^4)+o(x^3)=o(x^3)+o(x^3)=o(x^3)$.

Comment: Is that $x^4$ maybe $o(x^4)$ ?

Comment: No, as the ratio is equal to $1$. But you can say (trivially) that $x^4=O(x^4)$.

Comment: So every time I have $o(x^m)+o(x^n)$ and $m>n$, then  $o(x^m)+o(x^n) = o(x^n)$.? I'm so sorry for asking this many questions, you can ignore me if  you want, it'll be fine.

Comment: Impossible to ignore you – I love to help (as much as I can) . To answer your question, yes, that's correct. Another useful thing to know, that can help compute limits, if you  have two functions $f$ and $g$ such that $g=f+o(f)$, then $g\sim f$ (in the sense of asymptotic equivalence of functions.)

Answer (score 6):

You have$$e^x\sin(x)=x+x^2+\frac{x^3}3+o(x^3),$$and therefore$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x\sin(x)-x-x^2}{x^3}=\frac13.$$

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, but could you explain how you got that $\frac{x^3}{3}+o(x^3)$, because when I try to do it by myself I get $(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2))(x+o(x^2))$? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: You have$$e^x\sin(x)-x-x^2=\left(1+x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}6+o_1(x^3)\right)\left(x-\frac{x^3}6+o_2(x^3)\right)-x-x^2,$$where $o_1(x)$ and $o_2(x)$ are such that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{o_1(x)}{x^3}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{o_2(x)}{x^3}=0$. But then $e^x\sin(x)-x-x^2$ is equal to$$\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^5}{12}-\frac{x^6}{36}+o_2(x)+o_1(x)o_2(x)+o_1(x)x+o_2(x)x+o_2(x)\frac{x^2}2-o_1(x)\frac{x^3}6+o_2(x)\frac{x^3}6$$and it is clear that, if you forget the $\frac{x^3}3$ term, you have an expression which, when divided by $x^3$ has limit $0$ at $0$.

Comment: Another stupid question I have. But if I get $\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^5}{12}-\frac{x^6}{36}$ an divide it by $x^3$ wouldn't I get 1/3 then the rest goes to infinity? (I'm so sorry for asking this many questions)

Comment: If you divide $\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^5}{12}-\frac{x^6}{36}$ by $x^3$, what you get is $\frac13-\frac{x^2}{12}-\frac{x^3}{36}$, whose limit at $0$ is $\frac13$.

Comment: Oooooh, now I finally get it, thank you very very much for answering.

Answer (score 2):

The first limit is straightforward as one can write the Taylor series for $\cos x$ and $e^{-x^2/2}$ directly from memory without any calculations.

For the second one it is better to rewrite the expression as $$e^x\cdot \frac{\sin x-x} {x^3}+\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$$ and now we can see that desired limit is $1\cdot(-1/6)+(1/2)=1/3$.

In general one should avoid multiplication, division and composition of two Taylor series and instead focus on algebraic simplification of the expression under limit. In other words try to get coefficients of Taylor series from memory instead of calculating them.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall\;x\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;\;e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{ x^n}{n!}=\implies e^{-x^2/2}=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{4\cdot2!}-\ldots$$

and since

$$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\ldots$$

we get

$$\cos x-e^{-x^2/2}=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}-\ldots-\left(1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}8-\ldots\right)=-\frac{x^4}{12}+\ldots$$

and thus

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-e^{-x^2/2}}{x^4}=-\frac1{12}$$

The parts with "$\;\ldots\;$" mean there are powers of $\;x\;$ higher than $\;4\;$ , so at the limit those will cancel with $\;x^4\;$ in the denominator and all that part will tend to zero. Try to make this formal in your proof of the value of this limit, and attempt the other one in a simlar fashion.